# Divide canvas to pieces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to generate a screenshot of a url. This screenshot is displayed on the page and I want to be able to break it into pieces when it's clicked.

The output file that I get from html2canvas is a canvas element.
How can I "break" it to random pieces? Should I create new canvas element for every piece that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Html2Canvas* does not click . It just renders the DOM elements provided to it.So I dont think you can break the rendered canvas into pieces.

> **How it works**
>
> *The script traverses through the DOM of the page it is loaded on. It gathers information on all the elements there, which it then uses to
>   build a representation of the page. In other words, it does not
>   actually take a screenshot of the page, but builds a representation of
>   it based on the properties it reads from the DOM.*

But one thing you can do is  divide your DOM content into parts and the you can use *Html2Canvas* for every DOM pieces and you get the required result.

Comment: That's a nice idea, thanks.
I will test is later.